# VueJS with vue-socket-io not displaying anything

Tags: vue.js

Trying for days but without any luck.
I installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io.

I then added this code to my main.js vue file:

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket-io';
Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://localhost:3001/');
```

My node server is running on port 3001, and when I refresh my page I do see something happen i.e. the command prompt shows a random string i.e. "PLlVISTMrfO2BzCJAAAZ". This is my connection, so that part is working!

When I want to receive a message from my server I used this code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('connected with id: ' + socket.id)

    socket.on('SEND_MESSAGE', function(data) {
        io.emit('hello_world', 'Get you right back...')
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

When I send a message from Vue, it is received by the server, but when I try to send a message from the server to Vue it is never received.

My Vue code:

```
    created() {

        // Send a message to the server
        this.$socket.emit('SEND_MESSAGE', 'Hello Node!')

        // Listen
        this.$options.sockets.hello_world = (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log('something came...');
        }

    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I also tried this but this aint working either:

```
    sockets: {
        connect() {
            // Fired when the socket connects.
            console.log("server connected");
        },

        disconnect() {
            console.log("server disconnected");
        },

        hello_vue: function (data) {
            console.log('this method was fired by the socket server. eg: io.emit("customEmit", data)')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **npm** source you linked says that you have to **subscribe** to events to receive them dynamically, during runtime.

```
this.sockets.subscribe('EVENT_NAME', (data) => {
    this.msg = data.message;
});

this.sockets.unsubscribe('EVENT_NAME');
```

You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io#dynamic-listeners).

Your code is written according to the **[old documentation](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/blob/master/docs/OLD_README.md)** (I guess that's deprecated, no longer working).

I suggest you try it with the **subscribe** method.

**EDIT**

The solution was to update the used **socket package** to a better one, and handle the CORS errors in the node server.

New, better package: [npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io-extended](http://npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io-extended)

CORS error handling: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

GitHub informed me, that it found a **HIGH SEVERITY VULNERABILITY** in one of the dependencies used in this example.

***CVE-2018-20834***

*More information*

*high severity*

*Vulnerable versions: < 4.4.2*

*Patched version: 4.4.2*

*A vulnerability was found in node-tar before version 4.4.2. An Arbitrary File Overwrite issue exists when extracting a tarball containing a hardlink to a file that already exists on the system, in conjunction with a later plain file with the same name as the hardlink. This plain file content replaces the existing file content.*

Please be careful!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Muka! I tried that but I get an error:

Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.sockets is undefined"

When I use a subscribe.

Comment: Do you have a **sockets** property (object) in your component?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood you, yeah I have a properties object but it doesnt do anything when I add connect() and other stuff on it.

sockets: {
        connect: function () {
            console.log('socket connected')
        },
        customEmit: function (data) {
            console.log('this method was fired by the socket server. eg: io.emit("customEmit", data)')
        }
    }

Comment: I tried searching for "listener" and "subscribe" but I cannot find anything that works so far. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle it properly? I keep getting the same error "this.sockets is undefined", no matter how I do it.

Comment: If you could provide code that **should** work (including the server), and displays the error you experience, I’ll see if I can get it to work. I tried to replicate the situation, but unfortunately I didn’t have the spare time. Maybe you can upload it to github.

Comment: Yeah no problem! I will upload it to Github tonight. Thank you so much for your help so far :) Meanwhile I'll try to find a solution. I'll post an update here tonight with the Github link!

Comment: That’s nice of you, but keep it till the code is working :)

Comment: I uploaded it on Github. You should be able to download it from here: https://github.com/Devbizz/vueSockets.git The two files u need are main.js obviously and src/components/pages/Channel.vue.

Comment: Only able to see the sitemap-splitter repository

Comment: sorry, now you can see it! was private :(

Comment: OMG you are the man haha, I will download and see what you changed and how you did it. I cannot thank you enough, took me days and still zero progress haha! thank you so much!

Comment: Did you upload your changes btw? dont see anything changed haha :)

Comment: I see the message in the Terminal from the vue app, and also see the message from the server in the browser console. https://github.com/gegeke/vueSockets-new

Comment: Sorry, I was just messing with the github thing - I couldn't upload it yours in a new branch

Comment: I hope this really does what you want it to do. Please install it and see if it does.

Comment: And to make you sad for your lost time: you imported **vue-socket-io** in the main.js, and used the documentation of **vue-socket.io** to make it work... :p

Comment: I realized it when I imported it in vue-cli ui, and looked at "why is this package there twice?"

Comment: The solution was: change the package to a better one. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io-extended

Comment: It works flawless and this is indeed exactly what I needed! pffff... back to school for me hahaha, never would have found out that I needed to add those things to the node server :P and yeah the "dot" in the name... oh man, sneaky mistake lol! anyways thank you so much for helping me out, you are my hero!

Comment: Niiiiice! :D Happy to help! :) I modify my answer if somebody later stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me

````
export default {
  name: "App",
  sockets: {
    connection: function () {
      console.log("socket connected");
    },
    customEmit: function (data) {
      console.log('s'
      );
    },
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  created() {
    this.sockets.listener.subscribe("chat:message", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    clickButton: function () {
      // $socket is socket.io-client instance
      this.$socket.emit("chat:message", { id: "asasas" });
    },
    listenButton: function () {
      // $socket is socket.io-client instance
      this.$socket.on("chat:message", () => {
        console.log("data");
      });
    },
  },
</pre>```
````

Comment: Please include an explanation of the code Espartaco Parra.